# SQL Duplicates multi criteria selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am trying to create a query that removes duplicates based multiple rules.

Some sample data:

Column A:    Column B:

```
One    Apple
One    Pear
Two    Apple
Two    Mango
Three  Pear
Four   Mango
Five   Plum
Six    Mango
Zero   Banana
```

Essentially what I have been rattling about is that I would like the query to return the distinct pairs based upon duplicates from each column.    Meaning that the if there is a duplicate in A, all entries are removed based upon the column duplicates(example, two and two would remove two-apple, two-mango).  The same logic for B(ex, apple apple and mango mango being taken out)  So the final results would be:

Column A:    Column B:

```
Three   Pear

Zero    Banana
Five    Plum
```

Any pointers would be great.  I am on SQL Server.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi - sorry I should add that.  SQL Server.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is Three Pear in your results isn't Pear there twice?

Answer (score 0):

You could join back on the table and then select rows that have no matches (e.g. no duplicates).

```
SELECT a, b
FROM my_table source
LEFT JOIN my_table a_dups
    ON source.a = a_dups.a
    AND source.b <> a_dups.b
LEFT JOIN my_table b_dups
    ON source.b = b_dups.b
    AND source.a <> b_dups.a
WHERE a_dups.a IS NULL
    AND b_dups.b IS NULL
```

Typing this outside IDE so pardon SQL errors but hopefully should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

Creating sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ColumnA varchar(20), ColumnB varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('One','Apple'),
('One','Pear'),
('Two','Apple'),
('Two','Mango'),
('Three','Pear'),
('Four','Mango'),
('Five','Plum'),
('Six','Mango'),
('Zero','Banana');
```

Showing full data set:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

[image]

using Common Table expression with patrition by to identify duplicates in both columns:

```
    WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnA ) AS rn1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnB ) AS rn2  FROM #temp)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ColumnA NOT IN (SELECT ColumnA FROM CTE WHERE rn1 <> 1) AND ColumnB NOT IN (SELECT ColumnB FROM CTE WHERE rn2 <> 1)
```

Showing result after:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

[image]

Comment: That's up to the user if they want to delete or keep the duplicates I just assumed that they wanted to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @Hogan: I have also included the option of just querying in the new edit. Thanks

Comment: Also your results don't match the question -- One Apple should not be returned.  I believe you need COUNT() not ROW_NUMBER().  Not every use of windowing functions needs ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Hogan: Actually Three   Pear should not be in there either.

Comment: @Hogan: Ok See my edited answer. This should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing functions to get the count of the each field and then just check that the count is one for both.  Like this:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM (
  SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) as ACount,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB) as BCount
  FROM TABLE
) X
WHERE ACount = 1 AND BCount = 1
```